# Fill table cells, but empty the backgroundcolor first?

Tags: javascript, css

I am having a problem and i cant seem to solve it in my Javascript / CSS code.

I want to fill certain table cells background-color on a Buttonclick and with another button fill other cells with a different color, BUT "delete" the color from the first buttonclick first.

If I remove "fill_cellstransparent()" from the second Button it works, but cell [1] stays red and thats what i dont want.

anyone any idea?

EDIT: I kind of solved it, but does someone know how to give the cells ID's with letters, f.e. 1 and still works with function.fill_cellsred([A]) ? It doesnt seem to work if I use letters instead of numbers as cell id's.

Here is my first idea:

```js
function fill_cellsred($cells) {
  $cells.forEach(e => document.getElementById(e).classList.add('fillred'));
}


function fill_cellsgreen($cells) {
  $cells.forEach(e => document.getElementById(e).classList.add('fillgreen'));
}

function fill_cellstransparent($cells) {
  $cells.forEach(e => document.getElementById(e).classList.add('filltransparent'));
}
```

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 30px;
}

.fillred {
    background-color: red;    
}

.fillgreen {
    background-color: green;    
}

.filltransparent {
    background-color: transparent:;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
        <td id="4">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="5">5</td>
        <td id="6">6</td>
        <td id="7">7</td>
        <td id="8">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="9">9</td>
        <td id="10">10</td>
        <td id="11">12</td>
        <td id="12">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="13">13</td>
        <td id="14">14</td>
        <td id="15">15</td>
        <td id="16">16</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="fill_cellsred([1, 2, 3])">ROT</button>

<button onclick="fill_cellstransparent(); fill_cellsgreen([2, 3, 5])">GRÜN</button>
```

Comment: I'm aware of the "background-color: transparent:;"  ':' mistake here but doesn't help me. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the working code

```js
function fill_cellsred(nums) {
  $cells = get_cells(nums);
  $cells.map(e => e.classList.add('fillred'));
}


function fill_cellsgreen(nums) {
  $cells = get_cells(nums);
  $cells.map(e => e.classList.add('fillgreen'));
}

function fill_cellstransparent() {
  $cells = get_cells();
  $cells.map(e => e.classList.add('filltransparent'));
}

function get_cells(nums = []) {
  let $cells = document.querySelectorAll('table td');
  
  // $cells_final will be array in the end
  // so let's make $cells also an array
  // so there will be less mistakes in future
  $cells = Array.from($cells);
  let $cells_final = [];
  
  // filter cells by num
  if(nums.length) {
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      $cell = $cells[nums[i] - 1];

      if($cell) $cells_final.push($cell);
    }
  }
  else {
    $cells_final = $cells;
  }
  
  return $cells_final;
}
```

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 30px;
}

.fillred {
    background-color: red;    
}

.fillgreen {
    background-color: green;    
}

.filltransparent {
    background-color: transparent:;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
        <td id="4">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="5">5</td>
        <td id="6">6</td>
        <td id="7">7</td>
        <td id="8">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="9">9</td>
        <td id="10">10</td>
        <td id="11">12</td>
        <td id="12">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="13">13</td>
        <td id="14">14</td>
        <td id="15">15</td>
        <td id="16">16</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="fill_cellsred([1, 2, 3])">ROT</button>

<button onclick="fill_cellstransparent(); fill_cellsgreen([2, 3, 5])">GRÜN</button>
```

Actually I think you should use 
`e.style['background-color'] = 'green'` instead of classes, or remove classes each time `e => {e.classList.remove('fillgreen'); e.classList.remove('filltransparent'); e.classList.add('fillred')}`;

Comment: Thanks. With e.style['background-color'] = 'green' instead of classes it seems to work great. Much appreciated :-)

Comment: well i actually noticed that sth went wrong, cells [2,3,4] gets filled instead of [1,2,3] and just like on the other button everything is +1

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited answer, I forgot to add -1 on line 29 in js. Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making transparent the element, the best way is to reset your element means you can remove the existing class.

Here is the updated code.

```js
function fill_cellsred($cells) {
 fill_cellstransparent()
  $cells.forEach(e => document.getElementById(e).classList.add('fillred'));
}


function fill_cellsgreen($cells) {
fill_cellstransparent() 
  $cells.forEach(e => document.getElementById(e).classList.add('fillgreen'));
}

function fill_cellstransparent() {
document.querySelectorAll("table td").forEach(item=>item.classList=[])
}
```

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 30px;
}

.fillred {
    background-color: red;    
}

.fillgreen {
    background-color: green;    
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
        <td id="4">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="5">5</td>
        <td id="6">6</td>
        <td id="7">7</td>
        <td id="8">8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="9">9</td>
        <td id="10">10</td>
        <td id="11">12</td>
        <td id="12">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="13">13</td>
        <td id="14">14</td>
        <td id="15">15</td>
        <td id="16">16</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="fill_cellsred([1, 2, 3])">ROT</button>

<button onclick="fill_cellsgreen([2, 3, 5])">GRÜN</button>
```

Comment: Here is the problem, that EVERYTIME the table gets cleared so if the code is more complex and on 1 Button I wannt to add green&yellow colors f.e. only one color will be displayed, because in every color-code there is fill_transparent